# Python Tkinter OOP using Frame inheritance. Initialized labels won't show in GUI

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, inheritance

I have the following code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame):

 def __init__(self, parent = None):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    
    self.yearLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Label",width=5)
    self.yearLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    app = Window(root)
 
    root.mainloop()
```

However nothing will be outputted into the GUI unless I change the label so that parent is passed in instead of self e.g self.yearLabel = tk.Label(parent, text="Label",width=5). In all other examples I have seen 'self' passed in to display to a GUI. I am not sure what is happening here or what I have missed to get this Frame inheritance to work as in the examples.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you haven't put the frame `app` using any layout manager:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Frame):

 def __init__(self, parent = None):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent

    self.yearLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Label",width=5)
    self.yearLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    app = Window(root)
    app.pack()  # put the frame using Pack layout manager

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error. It should be `self.parent` not `self` for `Label` widget.

Change this:

```
self.yearLabel = tk.Label(self, ...
```

to:

```
self.yearLabel = tk.Label(self.parent, ...
```

Screenshot:

[image]